# Assembly: find the max number in an array, doesn't work

Tags: assembly

I'm developing on Mac OS X (FreeBSD)

here is the code

```
section .data
v dd 72,54, 89, 21, 0, 12
n equ 6

section .bss
max resd 1
section .text
global _start
_start:
    mov eax, 0
    mov ebx, [v]
    mov cx, n
    dec cx
    change_max:
        mov ebx, [v+eax*4]
        loop lp
    lp:
        inc eax
        cmp ebx, [v+eax*4]
        jl change_max
        loop lp
    return_max:
            mov [max], ebx
    exit:
        push dword 0             
        mov eax, 0x1             
        sub esp, 4
        int 0x80
```

I get a Segmentation fault:11 and I can't understand why, any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is no way for your program to terminate as you don't decrement the value of `cx`(which initially holds the array size) and stop the comparisons when it becomes `0`. Instead you keep looping and keep doing:

```
inc eax
cmp ebx, [v+eax*4]
```

which leads to segmentation fault because at some point you try to access past the array end, a memory which belongs to a segment which you don't own.

Comment: Another problem is that `LOOP` will use `ECX`, the entire 32 bits, not just the low 16 bits of `CX` and it doesn't seem like the provided code clears the top 16 bits of `ECX`.

Comment: the loop command decrease automatically the value in ecx, so my mistake was to use cx, instead of ecx. this is the correction I've made: mov ecx, n. Now it works, thank you.